# Problem with the store

Tags: elementary-website

Im traing to buy a a coffee Mug, but after I complete the Shipping information and I press "Check Out":

[image]

What can i do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the elementary web store and not the elementary software

Comment: This should be fixed as of 5 days ago. Relevant links: https://github.com/elementary/website/issues/1636 https://github.com/elementary/website/pull/1638